# Formula for annual interest with monthly payments

Tags: exponential-function

I'm trying to work out a short formula for calculating the final amount if paying in $1000 per month with an annual ROI of 45%...

[image: Spreadsheet]

At the moment, I am having to enter the ROI% in 12 times

`(45*12+45*11+45*10+45*9+45*8+45*7+45*6+45*5+45*4+45*3+45*2+45*1)/(12*100)`

but there must be a shorter way I've forgotten from my school days

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  Sum of series :)

`S = ROI * n(a1+an)/2`

`=45 * 12(1+12)/2`